# Em um SELECT dependente, com dados de cidades de uma tabela como deixar uma cidade em evidência?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Em um banco de dados, tenho a tabela Estados e a tabela Cidades. No site, quando escolho um estado, a lista de cidades é populada de acordo com ele. No meu código, está para aparecer por ordem alfabética, mas eu queria que a cidade de Ribeirão Preto ficasse no topo da lista do estado de SP.
Como faço para colocar Ribeirão Preto no topo da lista e o resto abaixo, considerando que são input de seleção dependentes?

Meu html

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
        <select name="estado" id="estado" class="form-control form-b" required>
            <option value="" class="option_cad"> ESTADO</option>
                <?php foreach($estados as $estado) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $estado->id; ?>" class="option_cad"><?php echo $estado->nome; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
        </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select name="cidade" id="cidade" class="form-control form-b" required>
            <option value="" class="option_cad">* CIDADE</option>
        </select>
   </div>
```

Meu PHP

```
public function pedidos() {
    if($this->form_validation->run('cadastro/pedidos')) {


            $orcamento = array(
                'nome'              => $this->input->post('nome'),
                'email'             => $this->input->post('email'),
                'telefone'          => $this->input->post('telefone'),
                'celular'           => $this->input->post('celular'),
                'id_cidade'         => $this->input->post('cidade'),
                'id_subcategoria'   => $this->input->post('subcategoria'),
                'descricao'         => $this->input->post('descricao'),
                'data_orcamento'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            );


            $idOrcamento = $this->superModel->insert('orcamento', $orcamento);


            $this->db->select('cidade.nome AS cidade');
            $this->db->join('cidade', 'cidade.id = orcamento.id_cidade');
            $this->db->where('id_orcamento', $idOrcamento);
            $endereco = $this->db->get('orcamento')->row();

            if($endereco) {
                $data['cidade'] = $endereco->cidade;
            }

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            $this->enviaEmailSossegue($data);

    $this->layout->view('confirmacao-pedido', $this->data);
    } else {

        $clausulas = array(
        'order' => array(
            array(
                'campo' => 'ordem',
                'valor' => 'ASC'
            )
        )
    );

        $clausulas['order'] = array(
        array(
            'campo' => 'categoria'
        )
    );

    $this->data['listaCategorias'] = $this->superModel->select('categoria', $clausulas);


    $this->data['estados'] = $this->superModel->select('estado');
        $data = array(
            'select' => 'valor, complemento',
            'condicoes' => array(
                array(
                    'campo' => 'campo',
                    'valor' => 'cadastro_bloco',
                    'like' => 'after',
                    'escape' => true
                )
            ),
            'order' => array(
                array(
                    'campo' => 'campo'
                )
            )
        );

        $this->data['textoBlocos'] = $this->superModel->select('configuracoes', $data);

        insertTag('js', 'jquery.maskedinput.min.js', $this->data);
        $this->layout->view('pedidos', $this->data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Como você esta fazendo, poste seu código.

Comment: Poste o código que exibe as cidades.

Comment: Posta pra gente o código PHP e o select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução :

no select das cidades faça algo do tipo

```
select cod,nome from cidades
order by (case when nome = 'Ribeirão Preto' then 0 else 1 end).cidades.nome
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigada!